# How to make animation value always run from 0 to 1

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create an animation tween from 0 to 1:

```
final Tween<double> _tween = Tween(begin: 0, end: 1);

late AnimationController _controller;

late Animation<double> _animation;
```

And for some reason, sometimes I need to call `_controller.reverse()` or `_controller.forward()`, and my `animation.value` runs from 0 to 1 then from 1 to 0.

How do I always get `animation.value` to run from 0 to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `_controller.forward(from: 0)` or you can create a function to get animation value like this:

```
double getAnimationValue(Animation animation) {
    final value = animation.value!;

    return animation.status == AnimationStatus.reverse ? 1 - value : value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.repeat()`.

```dart
_controller.repeat();
```

If you like to reverse while repeat

```dart
_controller.repeat(reverse: true);
```

Also, just to get on initial state, you can use

```dart
_controller.reset();
```

then can be start

```dart
_controller.forward();
```

Comment: Also check `_controller.forward(from: 0);`

Comment: thank you but _controller.repeat make my animation run forerver, I just want to run it single time

Comment: how about `_controller.forward(from:0);` or just `_controller.forward();`